# Optimizing batch image exports in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, parallel-processing, google-cloud

I'm creating a pipeline to train a machine learning model to create flooding probability maps at national scales using data in GEE via the Python API. For a given known flood event, I assemble data layers into a single labeled raster and then export them as a COG to a Google Cloud storage bucket. Later, I read the data back into an image collection, train the model, and save the outputs.

When I run the script for larger countries with a high number of known flood events (e.g., Australia, with 17 flood events in the EMDAT database), the process takes several hours. Eventually, we'd like to scale up to running this script for dozens of countries at once, so I'd like to optimize the export process. I'm already using the `ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage()` function, but I'm wondering if there's a way to parallelize the process with Apache Beam or something else to make it even faster (maybe the Xarray-Beam combo?). Here's what my current module for this part of my code looks like:

I have a module specifically for exporting the COGs and monitoring the task:

```
import time
import ee
from google.cloud import storage

def export_and_monitor(geotiff, description, bucket, fileNamePrefix, scale):
   
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(
        image=geotiff,
        description=description,
        bucket=bucket,
        fileNamePrefix=fileNamePrefix,
        scale=scale,
        maxPixels=1e13,
        fileFormat='GeoTIFF',
        formatOptions={'cloudOptimized': True}
    )
    task.start()

    # Monitor the task
    while task.active():
        print(f"Task {task.id}: {task.status()['state']}")
        time.sleep(180)  # Adjust timing as needed

    # Final status and explanation if failed
    final_status = task.status()
    print(f"Task {task.id} finished with state: {final_status['state']}")
    
    # Check if the task failed
    if final_status['state'] == 'FAILED':
        # Print the error message if the task failed
        error_message = final_status.get('error_message', 'No error message provided.')
        print(f"Task {task.id} failed due to: {error_message}")
    elif final_status['state'] == 'COMPLETED':
        print(f"Task {task.id} completed successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Task {task.id} ended with an unexpected state.")
```

Then, I run that via another module:

```
from data_utils.make_training_data import make_training_data
from data_utils.export_and_monitor import export_and_monitor
import ee
from google.cloud import storage

def check_and_export_geotiffs_to_bucket(bucket_name, fileNamePrefix, flood_dates, bbox, scale=100):
    """Check for existing GeoTIFFs and export if they don't exist."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    existing_files = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=fileNamePrefix))
    existing_dates = [file.name.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0] for file in existing_files]  # Extract dates from file names

    for index, (start_date, end_date) in enumerate(flood_dates):
        if start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') in existing_dates:
            print(f"Skipping {start_date}: data already exist")
            continue  # Skip to next iteration without exporting data for this date

        # If data for the date does not exist, proceed with export
        training_data_result = make_training_data(bbox, start_date, end_date)
        if training_data_result is None:
            print(f"Skipping export for {start_date} to {end_date}: No imagery available.")
            continue

        geotiff = training_data_result.toShort()
        specificFileNamePrefix = f'{fileNamePrefix}input_data_{start_date}'
        export_description = f'input_data_{start_date}'

        export_and_monitor(geotiff, export_description, bucket_name, specificFileNamePrefix, scale)
```